# extract pattern from string in python unexpected result

Tags: python, regex

```
x = pd.Series(['CA1234567', 'QWCEC']) 
x.str.extract(r'(CA|US)\d{7}$')
```

the expected result is `[CA1234567, Nan]`, but get `[CA, Nan]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the first group after the regex

```
In [105]: x = pd.Series(['CA1234567', 'QWCEC'])
     ...: x.str.extract(r'((CA|US)\d{7})$')[0].tolist()
Out[105]: ['CA1234567', nan]
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the number in the capture group

```
x = pd.Series(['CA1234567', 'QWCEC']) 
x.str.extract(r'((CA|US)\d{7})$')
```